# Changing cell format with Apache POI causes loss of data and unexpected behavior.

Tags: java, excel, formatting, apache-poi, openxml

I am using Apache POI to create, access and modify *.xlsx and *.xls files. I got stuck on changing cell formats(don't confuse with styles).

```
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue(100); // setting cell value with double makes it numeric -> 100 aligned to the right
cell.setCellType(1); // changing cell format to text -> 100.0 aligned to the left
cell.setCellType(0); // changing cell format back to numeric -> 0 aligned to the right
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.xlsx");
wb.write(fos);
```

One may think that changing between text and numeric format causes the data to be replaced with 0. However trying the same thing for more cells gives some more unexpected results:

```
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
  Row row = sheet.createRow(i);
  for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
    Cell cell = row.createCell(j);
    cell.setCellValue(i*j);
    cell.setCellType(1);
    cell.setCellType(0);
  }
}
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.xlsx");
wb.write(fos);
```

The expected output is Multiplication table. Well... it's not. Actually changing the range of i and j affects the results for the same cell addresses.

Is this a bug in Apache POI?
Maybe it's due to OOXML specification and it's actually Microsofts mistake?
Or is something wrong with my computer and your output files look like they should?

Comment: Could you explain some more about what you're trying to do? Only that whole setting the cell type thing isn't normally needed....

Comment: I am creating a custom API for manipulating Excel files. One of it's requirements is ability to change between the cell formats. Some people provide me with excel spreadsheet with tons of numeric data that is formatted as text in Excel. I need to be able to change all those strings into numeric data without loosing it. I guess for now I will have to store values from excel as variables in java memory, change their type (in java) and write variable as numeric into excel.

Comment: Your safest bet is to fetch it as a string, use java to turn it into a number, identify the format applied to the string, then set the numeric value + cell style with that format